# How to add a syntax checker to a major mode for flycheck?

Tags: flycheck

I have the following flycheck setup in my init.el

```
(use-package flycheck
      :after web-mode
      :config
      (global-flycheck-mode)
      (flycheck-add-mode 'javascript-eslint 'web-mode)
      :diminish flycheck-mode)
```

Now, I expect the line `(flycheck-add-mode 'javascript-eslint 'web-mode)` to add javascript-eslint as a linter whenever I have a buffer running web-mode. However, 
when inside a buffer using web-mode I get the following setup:

```
Syntax checkers for buffer .eslintrc.js in web-mode:

No checker to run in this buffer.

Checkers that are compatible with this mode, but will not run until properly configured:

  handlebars (disabled)
    - may enable: Automatically disabled!
    - predicate:  nil
    - executable: Not found

Flycheck Mode is enabled. Use C-u C-c ! x to enable disabled checkers.

--------------------

Flycheck version: 32snapshot (package: 20191108.2129)
Emacs version:    25.2.2
System:           x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Window system:    x
```

And if I try to manually select the syntax checker, I get:

```
Syntax checker in buffer .eslintrc.js in web-mode:

  javascript-eslint
    - major mode:  `web-mode' not supported
    - may enable:  yes
    - executable:  Found at /home/mfb/src/MyFantasyBasketball/frontend/mfb-spa/node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint.js
    - config file: found

Flycheck cannot use this syntax checker for this buffer.

Flycheck Mode is enabled. Use C-u C-c ! x to enable disabled checkers.

--------------------

Flycheck version: 32snapshot (package: 20191108.2129)
Emacs version:    25.2.2
System:           x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Window system:    x
```

Anyone have an idea what I'm missing?

P.S. For some reason my `:diminish flycheck-mode` line also doesn't work...

Edit: expanded use-package command

```
(progn
  (use-package-ensure-elpa 'flycheck
                           '(t)
                           'nil)
  (defvar use-package--warning313
    #'(lambda
        (keyword err)
        (let
            ((msg
              (format "%s/%s: %s" 'flycheck keyword
                      (error-message-string err))))
          (display-warning 'use-package msg :error))))
  (condition-case-unless-debug err
      (eval-after-load 'web-mode
        '(if
             (not
              (require 'flycheck nil t))
             (display-warning 'use-package
                              (format "Cannot load %s" 'flycheck)
                              :error)
           (condition-case-unless-debug err
               (progn
                 (global-flycheck-mode)
                 (flycheck-add-mode 'javascript-eslint 'web-mode)
                 (if
                     (fboundp 'diminish)
                     (diminish 'flycheck-mode))
                 t)
             (error
              (funcall use-package--warning313 :config err)))))
    (error
     (funcall use-package--warning313 :catch err))))
```

Also, I noticed it will work if I add the single line `(flycheck-add-mode 'javascript-eslint 'web-mode)` to my init.el. I just can't get it to work with use-package for some reason

Edit 2: `flychecker-describe-checker` output

```
javascript-eslint is a Flycheck syntax checker in `flycheck.el'.

  This syntax checker checks syntax in the major mode(s) `web-mode', `js-mode',
  `js-jsx-mode', `js2-mode', `js2-jsx-mode', `js3-mode', `rjsx-mode',
  `typescript-mode'.

  This syntax checker executes "eslint". The executable can be overridden with
  `flycheck-javascript-eslint-executable'.

  This syntax checker can be configured with these options:

     * `flycheck-eslint-args'
     * `flycheck-eslint-rules-directories'

Documentation:
A Javascript syntax and style checker using eslint.

See URL `https://eslint.org/'.

[back]
```

Comment: Something is going wrong because I manually did the add to mode and can see it supported for web-mode. What does flycheck-describe-checker say for javascript-eslint?

Comment: actually I suspect the :config line might need to be wrapped in a (progn depending on how old your use-package is. Viewing the expanded macro (I use macrostep-expand) would verify the whole form is being correctly interpreted.

Comment: @stsquad I added the full macro expansion. I don't see anything wrong and it's already wrapped in progn

Comment: What about the flycheck-describe-checker output? Have you tried applying the change manually?

Comment: @stsquad added to my edits. I already tried applying the change manually and that's also in my op.

Comment: OK well at least describe checker shows it working. So the only thing I can think of testing now is replicating in an emacs -Q environment.

Answer (score 3):

You gave us the answer yourselves. The `(flycheck-add-mode 'javascript-eslint 'web-mode)` statement has to be run before enabling flycheck-mode. Simply moving the addition of `web-mode` as supported mode of `javascript-eslint` before enabling the global mode worked for me:

```lisp
(use-package flycheck
  :config
  (flycheck-add-mode 'javascript-eslint 'web-mode)
  (global-flycheck-mode t))
```

You could also do it the other way around, enabling flycheck in the web-mode hook (not using global mode, though) :

```lisp
(use-package web-mode
  :ensure t
  :after flycheck
  :config
  (add-hook 'web-mode-hook
            #'(lambda ()
                (unless (flycheck-checker-supports-major-mode-p
                         'javascript-eslint 'web-mode)
                  (flycheck-add-mode 'javascript-eslint 'web-mode))
                (flycheck-mode t))))
```